# jQuery Modal box

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I want to use this modal box http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/, in jQuery.
Is there a version of it available in jQuery. Or is there any other model box available in jquery with same scrolling down effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look on this site

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html

they have beautiful modal dialog.

Comment: From this link I used toottips too.. nice one

Answer (score 0):

If you go to jqueryui.com they have a modal box that with some slight modification will produce the same effect.